# Make directory copies using find

Tags: shell, find, directory, cp

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories in it. Thus

```
/usr/local/src/ccl/ccl-1.8/x86-headers$ ls
elf  gl  gmp  gnome2  gtk2  jni  libc
```

Each of these directories has a further subdirectory `C` inside it, which contains a file `populate.sh`. I want to create a parallel group of subdirectories with the same structure, but with a random value appended to the directory name (the random value should be the same in all cases), and only containing the C subdirectory with the `populate.sh` file. These directories contain other files besides the `populate.sh` file.

This is for a makefile, so for simplicity should probably use standard unix utilties. I'm thinking find with the `-exec` flag, or possibly `xargs` would work, but I'm having trouble making sense of the documentation, and I have little experience with shell scripting. Perl might work, but I have not used it, and would prefer not to use it here.

I've been using something like `mktemp -u --tmpdir=.` to generate a random string in the past, but it is hardly ideal, so I'm open to other suggestions. Ideally I'd like a name that looks like `libc.tmp_xw3st`. Ie. `tmp_` followed by a 5 digit alphanumeric string.

So far, I've got a way of getting a listing of the top level directories. :-)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0

../gmp./jni./gl./elf./libc./gtk2./gnome2
```

A fuller directory listing is at the end of this posting. To summarize, I want to create additional directories like `x86-headers/libc.tmpvalue`, which only contains the further file `x86-headers/libc.tmpvalue/C/populate.sh`.

A sketch of a possible approach is to handle this in two steps as follows:

Step 1: Run over the list of top level directories using `find`, and create a corresponding directory structure eg `dirname.tmpvalue/C/` using `exec` or piping to `xargs` and using `mkdir -p`.

Step 2: Run over the list of top level directories again and cp `populate.sh` into the `C` subdirectories. This is a bit sloppy, because the list of directories in theory could have altered between the two invocations of `find`, but this is not an issue in this case.

```
/usr/local/src/ccl/ccl-1.8/x86-headers$ ls -laR

[...]

./jni:
total 96
drwxr-sr-x 3 faheem staff  4096 Jul 31 00:53 .
drwxr-sr-x 9 faheem staff  4096 Jul 31 00:53 ..
drwxr-sr-x 2 faheem staff  4096 Jul 31 00:53 C
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 19535 Jul 31 00:53 constants.cdb
[more .cdb files]

./jni/C:
total 12
drwxr-sr-x 2 faheem staff 4096 Jul 31 00:53 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 faheem staff 4096 Jul 31 00:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff  148 Jul 31 00:53 populate.sh

./libc:
total 1276
drwxr-sr-x 3 faheem staff   4096 Jul 31 00:53 .
drwxr-sr-x 9 faheem staff   4096 Jul 31 00:53 ..
drwxr-sr-x 2 faheem staff   4096 Jul 31 00:53 C
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 593125 Jul 31 00:53 constants.cdb
[more .cdb files]

./libc/C:
total 20
drwxr-sr-x 2 faheem staff  4096 Jul 31 00:53 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 faheem staff  4096 Jul 31 00:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 faheem staff 10544 Jul 31 00:53 populate.sh
```

Comment: @WarrenYoung: Thanks for your comment. To be clear, I didn't say Gilles' answer had problems. I said using `find` had problems (from my perspective), and I mentioned two. I think Gilles approach is a good way to go, and I just asked him for a couple of clarifications. I think it is the best of the answers here - the others all use `find`. It is true I haven't accepted an answer yet, but I usually wait for a bit. As you can see from my record, I generally accept an answer eventually. I'll update my other question to hopefully make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a job for `find`, since there is no recursion involved.

```
for x in */C/populate.sh; do
  mkdir -- "${x%%/*}$suffix"
  mkdir -- "${x%%/*}$suffix/C"
  cp -p -- "$x" "./${x%%/*}$suffix/C"
done
```

Remove the `-p` option to `cp` if you don't want to preserve the files' modification time.

To generate a random suffix, BSD/Linux [`mktemp`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=1) is as portable as it gets.

```
suffix=$(mktemp -u tmp_XXXXX)
```

If you want something vaguely random-looking and POSIX-compliant, this gives a string that changes every second and varies from location to location; you can't really do better with only POSIX tools:

```
suffix=$({ hostname; pwd; date; } |
         cksum | uuencode -m /dev/stdin | awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0,3,5)}')
```

If you put this code in a makefile, remember to:

- double all `$` signs;
- put all the code on one line, using `;` instead to separate shell instructions (you can use backslash+newline+tab to put a line break in the makefile, but that sequence is removed to build the shell command);
- start the shell snippet with `set -e`, so that it aborts if there is any error.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for the pointers. A couple of questions. 1) Use of `find` seems harmless to me, even if not strictly necessary. Can you elaborate on how your method works? Does your method match all directories, even those like `.foo`? 2) If you want some line of the makefile (which is a shell snippet) to abort on error, is the best way to prefix it with `set -e`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha 1) `*` doesn't match `.foo`. In a compilation tree, this is usually the desired behavior, skipping `.svn` and the like (though here the requirement to have a path `C/populate.sh` will exclude them anyway). Add `.[!.]*/C/populate.sh` if you have directories whose name begins with a dot. 2) Start a command with `set -e`. E.g. `set -e; for x in …`

Comment: Hi, Gilles. Having studied your example some more, it mostly does what I want, but I have some more questions. `for x in */C/populate.sh` matches x with anything of the form `*/C/populate.sh`. The construct `${x%%/*}` matches the first part of the string, namely the top level directory name. Can you elaborate on these two pieces of syntax, and/or provide references, please? Syntax like `%%` is a bit hard to google for. Thanks. I've decided to try to save these values to an array. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44554/4671 - I'll be updating that question shortly.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Search for `%` in your shell's manual in the section about parameter expansion. `${x%%/*}` is `$x` with the longest match for the pattern `/*` removed at the end, i.e. it's `$x` minus everything after the first `/`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. For the record, in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)  this corresponds to the bit starting with `${parameter%%word}`. One more thing: what is the function of the `--`? I tried it without e.g. `mkdir -p "${x%%/*}$suffix/C"`, and it still works.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `--` prevents the argument from being seen as an option in case it happens to begin with a `-`.

Comment: Neither your `uuencode` thing nor your `mktemp` thing is anywhere near to as close as you can get to a randomly generated unique id - `$$` does just as well and is just as likely to conflict as either of your solutions without the mess. I have no idea why you `mkdir` twice nor why you `--` - FaheemMitha provided a printout of the files already. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create a temporary partial clone of the current directory
tcopy=`mktemp -d /tmp/tmp_XXXXX`
tbase=`basename $tcopy`
find . -name populate.sh -print | cpio -pud "$tcopy"

# Randomize the clone
for d in "$tcopy"/*
do
    mv "$d" "$d.$tbase"
done

# Merge the clone back into the current tree
mv "$tcopy"/* .
```

This depends on a `mv` implementation that knows how to move whole directories across filesystems. GNU `mv` can, but I remember working on some old Unix boxes where that final line wouldn't work. You could use another `find | cpio` pass instead in that case. `mv` is more efficient if it works.

Comment: Any alphanumeric string would work for the temp name. So, it might look like `libc.tmp_txw2e` or something. I'd like the random string to look like `tmp_` followed by 5 chars if possible.

Comment: This doesn't do what I want. I want subdirectories to be created at the same level, as in my example. This creates a whole separate directory structure. If I am misunderstanding, can you provide an example session? Thanks.

Comment: Rewrote my answer to address these comments. If that still doesn't get it, edit your question to give a pair of `find . -print` outputs, with the before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of every top level directory using

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir {}".tmpvalue" \;
```

You can then iterate and copy the `.sh` file to each of these directories.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work, since `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d` actually includes the current directory too, which we don't want here. So that needs to be excluded somehow.

Comment: Ok, `rnd=$(tr -cd a-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c5); find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir {}".tmp_"$rnd \;` works.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about `-print0` as long as the file names are well formed. Below is an example that should do what you want:

```
rnd=$(tr -cd a-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c5)
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
   mkdir -p ${dir}_${rnd}/C
   cp populate.sh ${dir}_${rnd}/C
done
```

#### Explanation

- `tr -cd` deletes the complement of the specified pattern, alphanumerics in this case.
- `head -c5` takes the first five characters and exits.
- `while` runs the `read` command for every line that `find` provides.
- `read` assigns the directory from `find` to `$dir`.

Comment: This doesn't work quite right. If I remove the `cp` line, then only one directory is created, and that doesn't have the dir name in front of it, it's just a 5 char random string. So, I conclude that $dir is not getting assigned correctly, and also the looping is not happening correctly. Also the first argument in `cp` would not work - populate.sh is down two levels. If you could explain the `while read dir` bit that would be helpful.

Comment: `$dir` needs to be protected from other types of expansion, so to fix this put braces around it: `${dir}`. I've updated the example.

Comment: Use the `populate.sh` that makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If others search for how to copy `find` results and create intermediate directories, you can use `--parents` with GNU `cp`, `rsync -R`, `pax -rw`, or `cpio -pd`.

```
find . -type f -exec cp --parents -t /tmp {} +
  --parents creates intermediate directories in GNU cp
  -t specifies a target directory in GNU cp
find . -type f -print0|xargs -0I, rsync -R , /tmp
  -R is --relative
find . -type f|pax -rw /tmp
  -rw (read and write) copies files
  pax is required by POSIX but not LSB and not included by some Linux distributions
find . -type f|cpio -pdu /tmp
  -p (pass-through) copies paths from stdin to a specified directory
  -d creates intermediate directories
  -u unconditionally overwrites existing files
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd usr/local/src/ccl/ccl-1.8/x86-headers
printf 'd=%s ; mkdir -p ${d}'$$'/C
     cp ${d}/C/populate.sh ${d}'$$'/C\n' * | sh
```

That creates a directory named `${dir}${current_shells_pid}/C` for every one you showed in your `ls` output in the question. It then copies the file you want from the source to the target directory.