# Looping over directory entries in bash and saving to an array

Tags: bash, shell, directory-structure, make

(See update at the foot of the question).

This is a followup question to ["Make directory copies using
find"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44340/make-directory-copies-using-find).

This question involved manipulating a bunch of directories, This got
too complicated to handle in a single command, so I decided to go with
an approach which saved the list of directories to a bash array,
despite reservations about portability. It seems that the POSIX shell
standard (the Unix shell standard, as I understand it) does not have
arrays.

The makefile I'm using appears below. This works except for the last
step. A summary of what I'm trying to do follows.

As discussed in the earlier question, I want to loop over the
directory `x86-headers`, and collect into a bash array, a list of its
top level subdirectories that contain the file `C/populate.sh` (but may
also contain other files). In my test setup, for example there is only
one directory in `x86-headers` which contains the file `libc/C/populate.sh`, namely
`libc`.

I then perform some operations on these subdirectories. The most
important of these is that I make a temporary copy of each directory
which looks like `libc.tmp_g4zlb`. Namely dirname followed by 'tmp_'
followed by a 5 digit random string.

So, some questions:

1) As discussed in the earlier question, I'm looping over the
directory 'x86-headers'. Here I am still using find. @Gilles indicated
in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44434/4671) that this
was not ideal. He might be right. Problems with find here:

a) The values returned look like `./libc`. I don't want a leading
`./`.

b) The find command I'm using lists all directories. I only want to
consider those that contain a file with the relative path of
`C/populate.sh`.

The approach Gilles was using might be better, but I don't understand
it. See the `gilles` target below. I'd like to get the list of the
directories and save them to an array.

2) The bit that I'm having problems with is the last step, namely

```
echo "(progn (require 'parse-ffi) (ccl::parse-standard-ffi-files :$$i'.tmp_'$(RND)))" | \
/usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl -I /usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl.image; done \
```

The relevant bit is that I'm trying to pass the temporary value
`libc.tmp_g4zlb` to ccl, which is a Common Lisp compiler. Without the
substitution, it would look like

```
echo "(progn (require 'parse-ffi) (ccl::parse-standard-ffi-files :libc.tmp_g4zlb))" | \
/usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl -I /usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl.image; done \
```

This works. The version using `$$i` above doesn't. The problem seems
to be the leading `./`. Without that, it should work. For the record, the error I get is

```
? > Error: Too many arguments in call to #<Compiled-function CCL::PARSE-STANDARD-FFI-FILES #x488B8406>:
>        3 arguments provided, at most 2 accepted. 
> While executing: CCL::PARSE-STANDARD-FFI-FILES, in process listener(1).
```

This is, however, not the error that I get when passing `./libc.tmp_g4zlb` to the compiler. That error looks like

```
> Error: Filename "/home/faheem/test/foo/x86-headers/.\\/libc.tmp_g4zlb/C/**/" contains illegal character #\/
> While executing: CCL::%SPLIT-DIR, in process listener(1).
```

So it is possible there is something else going on.

3) Does the overall approach look reasonable? Please feel free to
suggest possible improvements, even if it involves a completely
different strategy.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

export SHELL=/bin/bash
export RND:=$(shell tr -cd a-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c5)
export CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY=$(CURDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf x86-headers/libc.tmp*

foo: clean
    PATH=$$PATH:$(CURDIR)/ffigen4/bin; \
    echo $$PATH; \
    export CURDIR=$(CURDIR); \
    echo $$CURDIR; \
    array=( $$(cd x86-headers && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ); \
    cd x86-headers && \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    echo $$i; done; \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    mkdir -p $$i."tmp_"$(RND)/C; done; \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    cp -p $$i/C/populate.sh $$i".tmp_"$(RND)/C; done; \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    cd $$i".tmp_"$(RND)/C; ./populate.sh; done; \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    echo $$i'.tmp_'$(RND); done; \
    for i in "$${array[@]}"; do \
    echo "(progn (require 'parse-ffi) (ccl::parse-standard-ffi-files :$$i'.tmp_'$(RND)))" | \
    /usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl -I /usr/lib/ccl-bootstrap/lx86cl.image; done; \

gilles:
    cd x86-headers;
    for x in */C/populate.sh; do \
    echo -- "$${x%%/*}$$suffix"; done; \
```

UPDATE: It is possible that the question (or questions) got lost in all the details. So, let me try to simplify things. In [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44434/4671), Gilles wrote

```
for x in */C/populate.sh; do
  mkdir -- "${x%%/*}$suffix"
  mkdir -- "${x%%/*}$suffix/C"
  cp -p -- "$x" "./${x%%/*}$suffix/C"
done
```

As I commented on his question, `x` here matches patterns of the form `*/C/populate.sh`. Also, `${x%%/*}` matches the first part of the string, namely the top level directory name. Now, something like

```
for x in */C/populate.sh; do                                                                                                                       
    myarr[] = "${x%%/*}"                                                                                                                    
done
```

would create an array containing a list of top level directories, which is what I want. However, I don't know what syntax to use. I need to use a counter which runs over the loop, like `i=0, 1,...` to index `myarr` on the LHS. If I had a working piece of code like this, it would go some way towards solving my issue.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please provide the output you get

Comment: Why don't you separate the shell parts out into proper scripts? You'll have less trouble with quoting and more readability than inline in that makefile.

Comment: @danielkullmann: updated with the error messages.

Comment: @Mat: sure, that might make sense, and I have vaguely thought of that. However, does putting it in a makefile make a difference beyond having to double the `$`'s? I haven't seen a summary of the things you need to watch out for. It is unfortunate that shell syntax and GNU Make syntax are similar, yet different, so that they tend to trip over each other. In any case, since the script is almost working, I;d like to go the extra mile and get it working.

Comment: @Mat (contd): The first thing I'd like to do is fix the issue with the `./` in front of the directory names, possibly by using something other than `find`, and then see what happens.

Comment: You say it yourself: "shell syntax and GNU Make syntax are similar, yet different"; which makes it really hard to mix if you don't master both 100%. First make your script work standalone. Once you have that (and if you somehow feel it's worth it), inline it in your makefile. At least you'll have a correct starting point. Escaping issues are hard enough in shell & make. When you combine both, you're asking for trouble. As for not using find, Gilles answer uses a for loop and shell globbing for that. Use that.

Comment: I'm with Mat: beyond a certain complexity point, shell code is better written in a separate shell script and called from the Makefile. Aside from quoting and escaping, you'll also be able to do proper indenting in the shell script. With code that ugly, you have a serious problem with people's eyes glazing over before they even finish trying to understand your question.

Comment: @Mat: I updated the question to be more specific, using Gilles' solution. I take your point about reducing the problem by using shell. In any case, the question I'm asking now has nothing to do with make.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: Ditto what I said to Mat. Personally, I don't think shell script in a makefile is that terrible (compare to complicated C++ code for example), but ymmv.

Comment: Sorry but TL,DR. Can you rephrase your question in less than 4 pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append things to an array in a loop, you can use something like:

```
for x in */C/populate.sh; do
  myarr=(${myarr[@]} "${x%%/*}")
done
```

See the bash [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) documentation for lots of stuff you can do with them.

Alternatively, you can use `+=` to append to an array (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)) like this:

```
  myarr+=("${x%%/*}")
```

---

A few comments:

> As I commented on his question, x here matches patterns of the form `*/C/populate.sh`.

That's not how I'd have explained it. `*/foo/bar` is a glob pattern. It is expanded by the shell to a list of all files/directories that match this pattern. (Try `echo */C/populate.sh`, you'll see all the matches printed.)
The `for` loop iterates over this set of matches, using `$x` as the loop variable.

> Also, `${x%%/*}` matches the first part of the string, namely the top level directory name.

`${x%%/*}` doesn't "match" anything. It's a string manipulation function that operates on `$x`. From [the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), `${var%%string}` removes the longest match of `string` from the end of `$var`. In this case, it removes everything from the first `/` onward and "returns" (expands to) that.

So to break the above three lines of code down, what happens is:

- the shell generates a list of items (files or directories) that match the glob `*/C/populate.sh`.
- for each of those, the loop body is executed with `$x` set to that item
- `${myarr[@]}` expands to the list of each item in the array
- `${x%%/*}` expands to `$x` minus everything from the first `/` onward
- `myarr` is then reconstructed with its old contents plus the new, stripped-down item.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, can you offer a more specific reference or break it down a bit? I've looked at your reference, but I don't see it. The `myarr[@]` is some kind of magic `for-each` operator, it seems.

Comment: There's nothing much to break down, the append is of the form `array=(${array[@]} $appended_element)`. Search for append in that page. See also http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html (${array[@]} expands to all elements of the array.)

Comment: To append an element to an array, you can use `myarr+=("${x%%/*}")` (note that the parentheses are necessary in bash).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was possible. Much nicer syntax.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the slow response. I eventually decided not to use arrays in this case after all, but it is good to know how to do so. Just one followup question - does `*/foo/bar` get expanded every time the loop passes over the top, or just the first time it enters the loop?